# Enable JSDoc intellisense on properties in unioned types?

Tags: typescript, intellisense, jsdoc, tsdoc

If I write doc comments on a property in a TypeScript type, they show up when hovering the property.

[image]

If I make the type a more complex union type, the doc comments no longer appear.

[image]

I can get the doc comments by referencing the property on the type.

[image]

Is there a way to enable doc comments for the properties on a more complex union type?